# Enable Play/Pause when background is true in Vimeo video embed options

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, vimeo

With the following parameters we can hide title, line, and logo but not like and add to watch later:

```
title=0&byline=0&portrait=0
```

With the following parameters we can hide the title, line, logo, like, add to watch later, play/pause and all other options but the video will autoplay and we can't pause the video.

```
background=1
```

How to enable Play/Pause when `background` is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not currently possible using our player.js API.

If you use the `background` parameter it is meant to be a typical background video running endlessly like you see on websites- autoplay, muted, no controls, looping.

So as a clear answer - At this point there is no way to hide those other icons programmatically. However, we have received the feedback and are looking into instituting the feature. If you are the video's owner though and have a paid account (basic users cannot edit embed settings), you have the ability to hide all of these things in the video settings. If you visit `https://vimeo.com/manage/[YOUR-CLIP-ID]/v2/embed` you will have the ability to change what appears in the embed such as: playbar, volume icon, Speed controls, Fullscreen icon, and all the Actions (Like, Watch Later, Share). There you can also choose to hide the title/byline/portrait completely as well.

Comment: Are the above settings (Like, Watch Later, Share) only available for Plus, PRO, Business, and Premium members?
Can we have the ability to change these settings like,watch later and share from a free/standard account?

Comment: Yes @Divya , these are features currently restricted to our paid accounts. I will clarify in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info R Sichel

Comment: @RebeccaSich Can I jump in here? We have a video, `background=1`,`controls=0` but in Chrome (MacOS) the pause button appears while the video is loading which, from your answer above shouldn't be happening. Is this known behaviour>