# Hide only Like, Watch and Share on vimeo video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vimeo

Can we hide only the like, watch and share options on the vimeo video?
I tried with `background=1` and few css but didn't work

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/236241664?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&transparent=0&autoplay=1" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" title="Funny Cat Videos For Kids" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" data-ready="true"></iframe>
```

Reference: https://jsfiddle.net/s4h4o52z/854/

Also tried with `title=0&byline=0&portrait=0` still unable to hide those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible if you are the owner of the video. Then you can do this in the embed settings page. Otherwise, it is not currently possible to do this programmatically. I provided more details in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616812/6156526)

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/terms

" 2.2.4. You will not alter, remove, replace, or mask any aspect of the Vimeo Player (including the playbar, logo, and like, embed, and share features) without Vimeo’s prior written consent. "



It is clear from Vimeo Terms that we are restricted to hide the options like,watch later and share on Vimeo video